# Is there a list of Excel VBA syntax differences in Compatibility mode?

Tags: excel, vba, compatibility

We have an old `.xls` file with macros that I was asked to convert to `.xlsm` (company policy blocking `.xls` files).
The problem is that after the conversion, some of the VBA macros no longer work. My guess is that this is due to the change from Compatibility mode in the original file.

Here is an example that used to work and now does not - the syntax is actually wrong according to the current documentation, but it used to work and now does not .. and I did not expect syntax changes when changing a file extension...

```
With Sheets(StartArk)
    .Rows("A9:IV10000").Clear
    .Columns("A:IV").ColumnWidth = 8.43
```

I have two questions:

- Is there a list of syntax changes between the two VBA versions?
- Is there a way to have an `.xlsm` using the old syntax?

Comment: No, there are no differences in VBA syntax due to compatibility mode. This syntax is fine.

Comment: `Rows` cannot get a column or cell reference - You need to specify the row numbers, eg `.Rows(9).Clear` or `.Rows("9:10000").Clear`, or you need to use `.Range("A9:IV10000").Clear`. I doubt that this ever worked in older versions of Excel.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I know the syntax is wrong but it worked (in many years) as long as the file was .xls with Compatibility mode. It stopped working when saved as .xlsm.

Comment: Time to install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and look at the code inspections.  Chances are that the old code made lots of assumptions about default members, some of which may have changed.

Comment: Default members did not change, what did is what the properties are willing to accept. To avoid the default members uncertainty you can use `.Rows.Item("A9:IV10000").Clear`, which will work in Excel 2003 but fail in Excel 2010. Likely in Excel 2007 they fixed `Rows.Item` so that it no longer accepts a full range address, which was arguably a bug.

Comment: @GSerg I would understand fixes between Excel versions, but I am talking about the same Excel (2016), same file, just saved differently. Or do you mean that that v.2016 includes an old parsing engine for Compatibility mode?

Comment: @freeflow: I did not know about Rubberduck - it found hundreds of issues, but not the two problems illustrated above...

Comment: `old parsing engine for Compatibility mode` - rather, the old objects that actually run the code. It's the code behind `Rows.Item` that behaves differently in compatibility mode, not the VBA parser.